# uploading a file in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion-9

We would like to know if there is a way to upload a file by using coldfusion.Our requirement is to upload a csv file..So intially we move the csv file data to a temporary table and then  we shud write a proc and call it  that would kick of the actual upload process.

Comment: [ColdFusion File Upload](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=coldfusion%20upload%20file&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) Make sure you do some basic research before asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, yes.  ColdFusion makes this is quite a simple process.  Just read the CF9 docs concerning cffile (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-738f.html)